# Is it possible to return enum from method?

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enum:

```
    enum ControlsId
    {
        f1,
        f2
    }
```

And I want to return enum type from the function, like this:

```
    public enum GetPostBackControlId(string str)
    {
          if(str = "btn1")
             return ControlsId.f1
          if(str = "btn2")
             return ControlsId.f2
    }
```

Is it possible to return enum  from method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public ControlsId GetPostBackControlId(string str)
{
      if(str == "btn1")
      {
         return ControlsId.f1;
      }
      else if(str == "btn2")
      {
         return ControlsId.f2;
      }
      return (ControlsId)17;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but note you'll get a compiler error that not all paths return a value..

Comment: also those assignments need to be comparisons

Comment: Sorry, I've just copy-pasted code from the question. Fixed. Tanks.

Comment: @MobileX I provided a solution that is more generic that may interest you.

Comment: ))  You know, "more generic" is not always better ;)  Upvoted anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I know an answer already exist, but something that may be a bit cleaner.

```
public TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(string content)
{
     return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), content, true);
}
```

The beauty of this method, it is generic and highly reusable.  As long as the value exist, it will parse into a valid `enum`.  Otherwise, it will throw an exception.  But if you intend to parse into an `enum` you tend to be aware of the type.